# What does "breakdown (weather)" mean and can I somehow avoid it?

Tags: railway-empire

I'm playing the campaign in Railway Empire (PC, via Steam) and on the "The West" stage, two of my locomotives have broken down because of "breakdown (weather)":

[image: Screenshot of broken down locomotive]

It is, indeed, thunderstorming over Sacramento, so there's definitely weather. But why is it causing my locomotives to break down, and is there some way I can avoid it? All traffic in and out of the city has come to a halt because of this.

Answer (score 1):

In [this Steam Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/503940/discussions/0/1638675549002313866/), one response says:

> Are you talking about random breakdowns? Those can't be avoided, they are random. Similar applies to trains hit by lightning bolts during storms.

You mention it was thunderstorming. Thus, I suspect your locomotive was struck by lightning, causing it to breakdown. And by the sounds of the Steam post, you can't do anything about it because it is *random*.

I also read [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/503940/discussions/0/1741094390472271738/) that discusses things you can do to lessen the chances of random breakdowns, but those seem related more to maintenence related random breakdowns, not external "acts of God" breakdowns.

Comment: Random breakdowns are actually labelled "Random breakdown", though.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I think what they mean is they are similar to them (they *randomly* occur).  They may be labeled differently, but still quite random.